# variable accessing

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a variable x in one class.And I want to access the updated x value in some other class.
There is so much of confusion.Can I use property?.Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you could access it by #import Classname, and then just use the getter that is created with the property. but first initialize the class you have imported..

```
#import "ClassY.h"
@implementation ClassX

ClassY * classY;
NSString * name;

...

name = [classY name];

...

@end
```

Comment: This doesn't let you respond to changes in the value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to be told when the value changes? Have a look at [Key Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

Answer (score 0):

To simply access an iVar in one class from another, a property is exactly what you want.

The syntax is :
in your .h

```
@interface myclass : NSObject {

    UIWindow *window;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

in your .m

```
@implementation myclass
@synthesize window;

...

@end
```

The `@synthesize` directive instructs the compiler to produce a lot of boilerplate code (as directed by the (`nonatomic, retain`) specifiers. In this case to handle thread safety and memory management.

Also note that in Objective-C 2.0 the iVar declaration `UIWindow *window;` is not required.

If you want to be notified in your second class when an iVar is updated, you need to look at [key value observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html). Unless you are writing a framework or some very dynamic code, that is probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this tutorial](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1969) will help you out..

If this is not what you mean, please rephrase the question, because i don't understand it..

*Edit: Or a [shared Instance](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/05/the-death-of-global-variables/) can be used*